# c - Segmentation Fault on Ubuntu 18.04 but not on macOS High Sierra SDL1.2

Tags: c, macos, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm working on a project and I recently ran into a problem which I was not able to solve yet. I hope you can help me out.
When I remove the following piece of code,the program runs well again.

```
int connect(void){
int x, y;
Indice i1, i2;
i1.x = indX;
i1.y = indY;
compared[cpt] = i1;
bool search = true;
int col = compare_color[i1.y][i1.x];
int count;
while (search){
    count = cpt;
    for (y=0; y < BUB_NY; y++){
        i2.y = a;
        for (x=0; x < BUB_NX; x++){
            i2.x = b;
            if (bub_array[y][x] == 1 && neighbour(i1, i2) && col == compare_color[i2.y][i2.x] && !already_compared(i2)){
                i1 = i2;
                neighbour_list[cpt] = i2;
                cpt++;                     
                compared[cpt] = i2;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count == cpt){search = false;}
}

return cpt;
```

Here is the output when debugging with gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/me/Desktop/projet_methodo/projet 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff259f700 (LWP 6341)]

Thread 1 "projet" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff62428b4 in caca_free_display ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff62428b4 in caca_free_display ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff6243620 in __caca0_end ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff7b902fc in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff7b6ec1e in SDL_VideoQuit ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff7b6f03f in SDL_VideoInit ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff7b46e4c in SDL_InitSubSystem ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff7b46ec4 in SDL_Init ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#7  0x00005555555557fb in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf48) at projet.c:175
(gdb)
```

Comment: Showing us just one function is like giving us only one chapter of a book. We are likely not gonna get the entire plot from it. If you want us to tell you what goes wrong, you need to give us enough information to go by (for the book analogy, it would be a synopsis of previous chapters). Read how one should create a [mcve].

Comment: Smells of *undefined behaviour* somewhere in the code you didn't post. Were there any compiler warnings?

Comment: Strangely `cpt` is not defined in your code, but whatever it is, the function modifies it. Is it a global variable? Do you call `int connect(void)` more than once? If so, the next time you call it, `cpt` will hold the value left over from the previous call.

Comment: @WeatherVane I bet you're on to something. Looks like if `cpt` has a bas value, either the global `compared` or `neighbour_list` arrays will have an reference into an unknown area..

Comment: so, you left the final closing brace in the source code and it compiled and ran?  I strongly doubt it.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after EVERY opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.

Comment: Strongly suggest:  minimize (or eliminate) global variables.  Instead, pass the needed info as parameters to the called functions and declare the variables in a upper level function, like `main()`.   It there is a lot of variables involved, define a struct to contain those variables, then just pass the address of the struct instanc.e

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and thereby be able to help you

Comment: `connect` is in the standard c library on Linux. Can you use a different name for your function?

Comment: Thank you folks for all these quick answers. Indeed, Mark Plotnick was right and the problem consisted only in the name of my function. I'm very glad that this worked out now. So I suppose that the reserved names aren't the same ones in Linux and Mac. Thanks alot, I can continue working on my project now.

Comment: By the way, cpt is a global variable and I use it correctly in my program, now everything works and I got no undefined behaviour.